# Not showing all of the label on the x-axis in Swift 2

Tags: swift, linechart, ios-charts

I am using the Charts framework (danielgindi/Charts). My line chart is not showing all of the text on the x-axis on the last value. See image below.

How can I ensure that the whole text is shown?

[image]

Comment: try xAxis.isAvoidFirstLastClippingEnabled

Comment: @Wingzero I tried that however it still cuts off the label

Comment: "chartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true" worked though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Other way: chartView.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0)